# PHP Composer autoload PSR-4 Class not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I started a new PHP project and wanted to use PSR-4 to autoload from composer.

Project structure looks like this:

```
project

__src

____model

_______User.php

__test

_____UserTest.php

__vendor

__composer.json
```

This is my Composer.json:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "src\\model\\": "model/"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my User.php

```
<?php
namespace model;

class User
{
    public function doSomething() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the UserTest.php

```
<?php
use model\User;

class UserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test(){
        $user = new User();
        $this->assertTrue($user->doSomething());
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Class 'model\User' not found.

Answer (score 3):

Your `composer.json` file is wrong. It should be

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "model\\": "src/model/"
        }
     }
}
```