# How to autoload a self-made Symfony 4 bundle with Composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

In a project with Symfony 4, I import a self-made bundle with composer

```
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
    "myusername/my-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"repositories" : [{
    "type" : "vcs",
    "url" : "git@github.com:myusername/my-bundle.git"
}],
```

The bundle is correctly installed but I got the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "MyBundle" from namespace "My\Bundle\MyBundle".

The bundle is loaded in the Kernel from the bundles.php file

```
My\Bundle\MyBundle\MyBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true]
```

Here you are the composer.json of my bundle:

```
{
  "name" : "myusername/my-bundle",
  "type" : "symfony-bundle",
  "autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
      "myusername\\MyBundle\\" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

And finally the main file of the bundle is MyBundle.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Bundle\MyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use My\Bundle\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\MyExtension;

class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        return new MyExtension();
    }
}
```

I'm aware that the problem is caused by the autoloader but I can't figure out how to fix it. I tried the composer dump-autoload command and I have consulted the following similar questions but without luck:

- [Symfony autoload not working for a custom Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126081/symfony-autoload-not-working-for-a-custom-bundle)
- [Composer Not Generating Autoloads For Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408059/composer-not-generating-autoloads-for-library?rq=1)
- [PHP Composer autoload PSR-4 Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670625/php-composer-autoload-psr-4-class-not-found)

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the file located in your folder structure?

Comment: vendor/myusername/my-bundle/MyBundle.php

Comment: Take a look at the psr-4 section of composer.json for some of your other bundles.  You don't include the actual directory (myusername) but you do need to spell out the full root namespace (My\Bundle\MyBundle).  So something like: "psr-4": { "My\\Bundle\\MyBundle\\": "" },  And of course be sure to run composer dump-autoload after making changes locally.

Comment: Ok it worked. Thank you, please write an answer and I will approve it...

Answer (score 1):

Just `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
```

Comment: I got the following error: "Could not scan for classes inside "/var/www/behave/vendor/gianluca78/merlo-crud-bundle/app/AppKernel.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder"

Comment: Without `AppKerner.php` ?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev It won't be.  The question is about a bundle being installed in vendor.  Not the app src directory.

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev the Cerad's comment fixed my problem. Thank you both